# Axios unbale to catch error when server sends 422 in try-catch bloc

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm using `axios` for my `HTTP` with `Vue.js`.But when I do the `ajax call`, everything goes well when `server` sends back `response data` with `200` success. But when there is errors,`server` does not execute the `catch bloc`.
Here is my ajax call in Vue.js

```
export default{
    data(){
        return {
            form:{
                email:'',
                password:'',
                password_confirmation:'',
                fname:'',
                lname:'',
                city:''
            },
            formError:''
        }
    },
    methods:{
        //This should be a POST method through axios
        register:async function(){
           try{
               const res=await axios.post('api/register',this.form);
               console.log("Ba donnees : ",res.data);
           }catch(err){
               console.log("Erreeer",err.response);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my register controller:

```
private function validateForm($data){
        return Validator::make($data,
        [
            'fname' => ['required', 'string','min:2' ,'max:255'],
            'lname' => ['required', 'string','min:2' ,'max:255'],
            // 'mname' => ['string','min:2' ,'max:255'],
            'company' => ['string','min:2' ,'max:255'],
            'title' => ['string','min:2' ,'max:255'],
            'phone_number' => ['string','min:13' ,'max:13'],
            'city' => ['required', 'string','min:2' ,'max:100'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed']
            // 'password_confirm'=>['required','string']
        ]
      )->validate();
    }
    //Register
    public function register(Request $request){
        $data=$this->validateForm($request->all());
        $data['password']=Hash::make($data['password']);
        $user=new User($data);
        $user->save();
        return response()->json($user);

    }
```

When everything goes fine, I get the expected result of my `try` but in case of `POST http://localhost:5000/api/register 422 (Unprocessable Entity)` the is trying to log the statement in `try`.

But when I go in the network tab, I see the returned error `JSON` like this

> {"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"fname":["The fname
>   field is required."],"lname":["The lname field is
>   required."],"city":["The city field is required."],"email":["The email
>   field is required."],"password":["The password field is required."]}}

Comment: Do you use any [axios interceptor](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors)? It may be the cause of your problem. Interceptor catches your error and does not send it back to you

Answer (score 2):

If you are using axios interceptor globally in some main js file, then it will not catch error for individually axios call.
To solve that you should do "throw error; " like below where the axios interceptor is used.

```
api.interceptors.response.use(     
(response: AxiosResponse) => response,     
(error: AxiosError) => {       
   if (error.response?.status === 401) {         
      signOut();       
   }       
   console.log('throwing error');       
   throw error;     
},   
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Axios is not sending exception when http error is returned, you should use axios.catch instead:

```js
axios
  .post('api/register',this.form);
  .then(res => { console.log("Ba donnees : ",res.data) })
  .catch(err => { console.log("Erreeer",err.response) });
```

Comment: I've tried your code,but it doesn't change anything

Comment: You are using then/catch, he uses async/await, and in async/await catch block is not specified instead, all async function is in a try/catch block. Therefore your code and his code are identical

Comment: I've tried to change my code and replace with the one given by AzurInspire,but it does not solve the problem

Comment: I added your code to minimal new Laravel project and it is working out of the box like it should: https://github.com/azurinspire/stackoverflow-54882280

So I think it has something to do with your environment, not that code itself you posted here.

Answer (score 0):

You can define when the response should be caught with validateStatus property, like this

```
axios.post('api/register', {
  validateStatus: function (status) {
    return status < 400; // Reject only if the status code is greater than or equal to 400
  }
})
```

Comment: hmm.. your response in network tab looks like bad parsing, did you set Content-Type to application/json ?

Comment: also, your initial values are empty strings, when does it change? Looks like you are calling register before filling the form with data.

Comment: When i submit the form with good values,the post method is executed successfully,but i leave the fileds empty because i would like to catch errors messages so that i can customize error message in the form

Comment: Yes i've set Content-Type to application/json