# Handling 422 error with axios inside service.js

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have a service.js which has some axios requests. When I post something using this service from view, I can't handle errors, because all errors falls into success chain instead of error.
This line is from service.js

```
async createIsp(payload) {
    return await apiService.post('/isp', payload)
}
```

And this one is from view:

```
function saveIsp() {
  clicked.value = true
  ApiService.createIsp({isp_name: newIsp.value}).then((data) => {
  clicked.value = false
   //all response falls here... even its error.
  //router.push({name: 'isp'})
  }).catch(e => console.log(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70542347/3054818

This is the solution. I am using interceptors, and I should throw error.